# Getting SSL certificate error when Azure try to access URL configured in Azure App Proxy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have configured an Application in Azure App Proxy to access my application via an App Proxy Connector in our network. I observed that in Event Viewer for AAD application connector, I get 'The SSL server certificate presented to Microsoft AAD Application Proxy Connector by the backend server is not valid; the certificate is not trusted' error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If we dont have a trusted certificate, we can disable SSL certificate validation via:
[image]